# Speed up the drawing of many points on a HTML5 canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to draw a lot of points on a HTML5 canvas, and it is taking pretty long. My code looks like this:

```
var points = getPoints() // Array of {x,y,color}
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
   ctx.fillStyle = points[i].color
   ctx.beginPath()
   ctx.arc(points[i].x, points[i].y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
   ctx.fill() }
```

I am wondering what performance tweaks I could do to speed this up. I only have 5 different colors. For example, would I benefit form sorting the points list on-the-fly to change `ctx.fillStyle` only 5 times instead of one time per point?

Comment: I think this is a pretty slow line: `ctx.arc(points[i].x, points[i].y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)` Try drawing simple rectangles, and see if that speeds it up. (IMHO, it should...)

Comment: I tried it and yes, it does speed up. I don't see how that helps however.

Comment: I think if you set up a fiddle it would be easier for people to tweak it, here's some modifications I can think of to make it a little faster (maybe) -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4WTaQ/) ...

Comment: @Stewie drawing an arc needs a lot of computation. Filling a rectangle is a lot simpler...

Comment: How many is "many", and how long is "pretty long" ?

Comment: @ppeterka, I know, but I need circles and not rectangles, that's what I mean.

Comment: @Alnitak around 3k points per canvas. On a tile configuration of around 8x6 canvases. It is taking a couple of seconds, total.

Comment: @Stewie look at Alnitak's answer: you should gather each of the 5 color dots into different arrays, (or array of arrays to ensure flexibility for future developments), and go through them one by one.

Comment: @ppeterka actually I think the preferred solution (given the small number of colours) wouldn't involve changing `.fillStyle` at all, hence no need to create sorted arrays.

Comment: @Alnitak your solution is very nice - one of those when I'm sad that I can't upvote more than once... I had a logically similar thought, but using an off-screen canvas didn't come to my mind. My idea would have been to use small GIFs of the different color points - but I think that soing so would have been even slower than drawing the arcs one by one...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> For example, would I benefit form sorting the points list on-the-fly to change ctx.fillStyle only 5 times instead of one time per point?

In my experience, yes - changing `.fillStyle` frequently is quite expensive.

I had code that was plotting a large number of rectangles in a canvas and the time to plot rectangles with only two infrequently varying colours was significantly better than plotting with many frequently changing colours.

Anyhow, since you only have five different colours:

1. Create an off-screen canvas into which you can draw five circles
2. Use `.drawImage()` to blit the right colour circle into your destination canvas without having to recalculate the arc coordinates
3. Assign `points[i]` to an local variable inside the loop to avoid dereferencing it over and over.

On my laptop this code is drawing 3000 circles on a 400x400 canvas in 7 milliseconds:

```
var colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'magenta'];
var n = colours.length;
var r = 10;
var d = r * 2;

var off = document.createElement('canvas');
off.width = n * d;
off.height = d;
var ctx = off.getContext('2d');  

for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    ctx.fillStyle = colours[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(i * d + r, r, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
var t0 = Date.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 3000; ++i) {
    var c = Math.floor(n * Math.random());
    var x = Math.floor(canvas.width * Math.random());
    var y = Math.floor(canvas.height * Math.random());
    ctx2.drawImage(off, c * d, d, d, x - r, y - r, d, d);
}
var t1 = Date.now();
alert((t1 - t0) + "ms");
```

​See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Dpgts/

Comment: Wow, mine does it in 3ms. Impressive. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Stewie BTW, if your circles don't overlap you can probably speed this up a lot using `.putImageData`.

Comment: They don't. You mean instead of .drawImage()?

Comment: @Stewie I did, but I just tried it and it was actually slower.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dpgts/137/ drawing a million circle takes a lot of time (approx 9 seconds)

Comment: In 2018, now both the arc() function and context changes are a lot faster in both FF and Chrome, and the speed difference is not as big as before. These days, I can draw 70k r=3 circles in 400 msecs, the drawImage() version is only 2x faster. So for most applications, I think this optimisation is not needed anymore.